# Connection to Remote SQL Server 2012 from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssms

There is a weird problem that I am facing. I have Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. A few days back I was easily able to connect to the remote database that resides on another PC on the network with SQL Server Management Studio installed through the following procedure:

1. Goto Server explorer
2. Connect to the database
3. Browse the server name. It came as `HO-IT-WS-08\SQL2012`. Select it.
4. Browse the database names. Select the relevant database

The test connection used to be successful. However now, doing the same procedure my visual studio crashes once i perform the 4th step and restarts. It is like this. I select the server name browse the databases and the visual studio crashes restarting. I checked all the things but am not able to figure out the issue. Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try entering server name without browsing it?

When you go for browsing, VS queries the network for the Sql Server browser services and "hangs" until it receives response.

Maybe the SqlServer browser has been disabled? Go to SqlServer Configuration Manager, and check for SqlServer Services / Sql Server Browser.

Comment: it browses. I select the server. But when i come below browse the databases. It says loading databases and visual studio restarts crashing. I even re installed visual studio 2013 premium but the problem still stands!